# A fixed point problem

Tags: gn.general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $A = \lbrace (tr,1-t)\; | \; t \in [0,1], r \in \Bbb{Q}\rbrace$. Is it true that any continuous function from $A$ into $A$ has a fixed point?

Comment: Is the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Comment: Yes, the usual topology

Comment: I don't understand the problem. $A$ is homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$. So everything follows from the Brouwer fixed-point theorem (it's variant for the dimension 1). The statement of the problem looks strange.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Would you please tell why $A\cong [0,1]$ ?

Comment: This is a general theorem: every bijective and continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, see R.Engelking, General topology, 3.1.13, see also Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#cite_note-10 (the properties of Hausdorff spaces).

Comment: Of course, this works only if I understand you correctly: the topology on $\mathbb R^2$ must be the usual topology of direct product of two $\mathbb R$, and each of those $\mathbb R$ is endowed with the usual topology of $\mathbb R$ (i.e. intervals $(a,b)$ form a base of open sets).

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Actually you claim is not true. Since if you delete any point of $A$ which lays on the x-axes then the reminder is still connected. But $[0,1]$ has not this property

Comment: @dimo Something is wrong, we do not understand each other. You consider a map from the closed interval $[0,1]$ into the plane $\mathbb R^2$ acting by formula $t\mapsto (tr,1-t)$ -- is this correct? And $A$ is  the image of this map. If this is correct (and $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R^2$ have usual topology), then this map is a homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $A$. (By the way, in this case it doesn't matter whether $r$ belongs to $\mathbb Q$ or to $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov No ! $r$ is not fixed as it is clear from the statement of the problem above.

Comment: Oh, I missed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (I assume $A$ has the induced topology). The point $V:=(0,1)$, common endpoint of all segments $S_r:=\{(rt,1-t): t\in[0,1]\}$, is either fixed by the continuous function $f:A\to A$, or it is mapped into some $S_r\setminus\{V\}$. But then $f $ has a fixed point on $S_r$.

Comment: To prove the last statement, we may consider another alternative: either $S_r$ is mapped into itself, so $f_{|S_r}$ has a fixed point there, or not, in which case some point $W\in S_r$ is mapped to $V$ by connection (this because $A\setminus\{V\}$ is disconnected): but then $f$ exchanges $V$ and $W$ and has a fixed point in between.

Comment: Either it does or not: if it does not, then it exchanges two points, and in this case you do not need $f(S_r)\subset S_r$ to conclude.

Comment: (sorry, "exchange" is not the right word. What I mean is: in the former case  we have $V < f(V)$ and $W > f(W)$ in the order of $S_r$)